# LibreOffice Calc, Fill in Differenet Numbers of Empty Cells with Above Value

Tags: libreoffice, auto-form-fill

I have two columns of data currently in data like this (i.e., varying number of blank cells in Column B):

> Column A       Column B
>   000                Alice
>   001                
>   002                
>   003                
>   004                Bob
>   005                Carlos
>   006                
>   007                Eve

I'd like to have the value in Column B fill in the empty cells below it—even though there are different numbers of blank cells or sometimes no blank cells.  So the end result would look like this:

> Column A       Column B
>   000                Alice
>   001                Alice
>   002                Alice
>   003                Alice
>   004                Bob
>   005                Carlos
>   006                Carlos
>   007                Eve

Anyone know how to automate doing this?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

While there is one answer already. I used the following approach.

In a third column, C, I put the Value of "Alice" in the C1 position, and in the C2 postion I put `=IF(B2="",C1,B2)`. Meaning, if the column to the left is empty, use the item above me. Use that formula for the entire column. I then would copy the column, and `paste special` on top of the original column and while ensuring only the `text` option was selected.

Answer (score 0):

This method selects the empty cells, then copies the name from the cell above into that cell.

- Select the desired range of cells that need to be filed

[image]

- In the 'Home Tab', click on **Find & Select** -> **Go To Special...**
- Select the **Blanks** option and click **OK**

[image]

- Type `=B2`

[image]

- Press **Ctrl + Enter** to copy into selected cells

The cells should be filled now, but with formulas and not the contents

- Select the entire range of cells again
- Copy them then press **Ctrl + Alt + V** for Special Paste
- Select **Values** from the Paste area and **None** from the Operation area

[image]

Answer from [Source](http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/771-excel-fill-blank-cells-with-value-above.html)

Comment: That does it!  Thank you so much for the great and clear answer.  Cheers!